# java regular expression mismatch

Tags: java, regex

I want to use recursive to split string. I use sting `asd>=123` to test

in first one, it success, but in second one, it enter else condition.

`s` may be "123>=asd;",  "123+456",  "654*123"

```
boolean SplitString( String s ) {

    if ( s.matches("^\\d+.*") ) { // number         
      parser.Add( s.substring( 0, subindex ) );
      if ( subindex == s.length() )
        return true;
      returnType = SplitString( s.substring( subindex, s.length() ) );
      return returnType;
    } // if 
    else if ( s.matches( "^(<|>|<>|:=|=|;|<=|>=|\\+|-|\\*|/.)*" ) ) { // operator
      subindex = SplitSign( s );

      parser.Add( s.substring( 0, subindex ) );
      if ( subindex == s.length() )
        return true;
      returnType = SplitString( s.substring( subindex, s.length() ) );
      return returnType;      
    } // else if
    else if ( s.matches( "^_?\\w+.*" ) ) { // variable
      for ( int i = 0 ; i < s.length() ; i++ ) {
        if ( !Character.isAlphabetic( s.charAt( i ) ) && !Character.isDigit( s.charAt( i ) )  && s.charAt( i ) != '_' ) {
          subindex = i;
          i = s.length(); // break loop
        } // if
      } // for


      parser.Add( s.substring( 0, subindex ) );
      if ( subindex == s.length() )
        return true;
      returnType = SplitString( s.substring( subindex, s.length() ) );
      return returnType;      
    } // else if 
    else { // not above
       return false;
    } // else
  } // SprlitString()
```

But it didn't work. What did I miss?

Comment: A couple of parentheses?

Comment: I tried it before, but it can't match( `^(<=)|(>=)|(<>)|(:=)|(=)|(;)|(<)|(>)|(\+)|(-)|(\*)|(/).*` )

Comment: Show your code. "it didn't work" is not a very clear problem statement as well.

Comment: Since you include the start anchor `^` you need to exlude it from the options, i.e. use the parantheses like this: `^(<=|>=|...).*`. Besides that you might be able to simplify your expression if you can live with some false positives, i.e. you could use something like `^[<>:=;\+\*/][>=]?.*` - which would match strings like `==` and `+>` as well, not sure if you'd want that.

Comment: When you say "it didn't work", do you mean "it doesn't compile?" or is the code you actually have different from the code you posted?

Comment: sorry for Insufficient information.

Comment: That's nice, but you should add the values of `s` that you would like to match

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex reduces to `(?:[-*+;=<>]|:=|/.)*`, however I believe
the `matches` method must match the *entire* string.

That means the start and end anchors are implicit and can be excluded.

So, unless your string is empty or contains *entirely* those characters
I don't believe it will match.

Comment: Your welcome. No question is bad though. Keep trying.